# Как парсить @import?

Tags: preg_match, php

Добрый день!

Есть код:

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter);
@import"reset.css";@import"pro_pages_style.css";@import"grid.css";@import"forms.css";@import"prettyPhoto.css";@import"jquery.snippet.min.css";
@import"../skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css";@import"../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css";
body{background:#212d32;font:14px/24px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;color:#7d919b;position:relative;min-width:960px;}
html,body{height:100%;}
p,.p{padding-bottom:24px;}
.p0 {padding-bottom:0 !important;}
.p1 {padding-bottom:10px;}
.p2 {padding-bottom:15px;}
a{color:#6ed3e5;outline:none;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline}
```

Мне нужно с помощью регулярок вытащить в массив все адреса стилей, типа grid.css,reset.css, и.т.д.

Я пробовал использовать такой код:

```
    $re = '/(t\"(.*)\";)/'; 
$str = ' @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter);\n@import"reset.css";@import"pro_pages_style.css";@import"grid.css";@import"forms.css";@import"prettyPhoto.css";@import"jquery.snippet.min.css";\n@import"../skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css";@import"../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css";\nbody{background:#212d32;font:14px/24px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;color:#7d919b;position:relative;min-width:960px;}\nhtml,body{height:100%;}\np,.p{padding-bottom:24px;}\n.p0 {padding-bottom:0 !important;}\n.p1 {padding-bottom:10px;}\n.p2 {padding-bottom:15px;}\na{color:#6ed3e5;outline:none;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;}\na:hover{text-decoration:underline}';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Но он не работает, подскажите пожалуйста.

**[РЕШЕНО]**

```
    $re = '/@import\"(.*)\";/U'; 
$str = ' @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter);\n@import"reset.css";@import"pro_pages_style.css";@import"grid.css";@import"forms.css";@import"prettyPhoto.css";@import"jquery.snippet.min.css";\n@import"../skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css";@import"../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css";\nbody{background:#212d32;font:14px/24px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;color:#7d919b;position:relative;min-width:960px;}\nhtml,body{height:100%;}\np,.p{padding-bottom:24px;}\n.p0 {padding-bottom:0 !important;}\n.p1 {padding-bottom:10px;}\n.p2 {padding-bottom:15px;}\na{color:#6ed3e5;outline:none;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;}\na:hover{text-decoration:underline}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: А какие регулярки вы уже пробовали ? что не получилось ?

Comment: Обновил. Указал что пробовал.

Comment: А что получается (выведете результат)?

Comment: О господи, что ж вы все всё всегда регулярками-то парсите? Ну помогут вам пару раз на форуме, проблемы же будут всегда.

Comment: @VladD а что вы предлагает кроме регулярок ещё использовать?

Comment: @chuikoff, просто надо **правильно проектировать** системы обработки информации.

Проектировать так, что бы вопрос о парсинге **кода** вообще не вставал.

Comment: @chuikoff: разумеется, полноценный парсер. Можно его даже написать на lex/yacc, или лучше взять готовый, их тысячи. Для CSS 30 секунд в гугле выдали вот что: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1289-PHP-CSS-parser-class.html

Comment: @avp: разве это Unix way? Там же вроде весь обмен информацией идёт в текстовой форме, а не в бинарной. Или я не в курсе текущих трендов?

Comment: @VladD, конечно, обычно в текстовой. Но при чем здесь обмен *кодом*, который нужно парсить?

Comment: @avp: думаю, ТС парсит CSS, причём чужой CSS. Если CSS свой, конечно, надо не извращаться с парсингом, а получать данные в нормальной форме, как вы и писали 4 часа назад.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий пример на http://ideone.com/LnZLGL
Не учитываются различные хитросплетения синтаксиса, это не входило в цель задачи.
Ничего трудного нет, все хорошо прокомментировал:

```
$re= <<<HEREDOC
    @import\\s*          # @import за которым пробельные символы
    (")?                 # кавычка, сохраняем в первую группу
    (?(1) |              # если совпала первая группа, то ничего не надо
         ((?<=\\s)url\\s*\() # ИНАЧЕ скобочка c url, сохраняем во вторую группу 
    ) #  конец ?(1)
    (?(1)|(?(2)|^))      # фэйлим совпадение, если ни одна из двух групп
                         # не совпала

    (                    # третья группа для сохранения результата
        (?(1)            # если была первая группа
            [^"]++ |     # ТО включаем в результат все НЕ кавычки
            [^\)]++      # ИНАЧЕ включаем все НЕ скобочки
        ) #  конец ?(1)
    ) # конец 3-ей группы
    # далее две строки принципиально не нужны- просто для полноты конструкции
    (?(1)                # если была первая группа
         " |             # ТО кавычка
         \)              # ИНАЧЕ скобочка
    ) #  конец ?(1)

HEREDOC;

preg_match_all("/$re/sux", $text, $arr);
var_dump( $arr[3] );
```

Comment: Всё верно, вся проблема была в том что я использовал preg_match, вместо preg_match_all

Comment: С чем это связано? preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'p'  не могу понять где этот неправильный модификатор

Comment: Вы где-то не экранировали слэш за которым идет символ п

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦ Верно. Ещё такой момент, как сделать чтобы в $arr[3] не было http:// , и обязательно было .css, чтобы избавится от таких конструкций как  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter); которые мне не нужны.

Comment: Это не имеет отношения к текущему вопросу. Создайте новый.  
Вообще, я перестал отвечать на простые вопросы по регулярным выражением:  
Они не имеют практической ценности, потому что универсальных регулярных выражений не существует- они все заточены под слишком узкие конкретные задачи.  
Просто кто-то переоткрыл вопрос, после того как я его закрыл, а раз вопрос посчитали ценным, то я дал ответ.